# Pythonic way to only do work first time a variable is called

Tags: class, variables, python, precompute

my Python class has some variables that require work to calculate the first time they are called. Subsequent calls should just return the precomputed value.

I don't want to waste time doing this work unless they are actually needed by the user.
So is there a clean Pythonic way to implement this use case?

My initial thought was to use property() to call a function the first time and then override the variable:

```
class myclass(object):
    def get_age(self):
        self.age = 21 # raise an AttributeError here
        return self.age

    age = property(get_age)
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking about memoization?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization.  This is pretty common OO design pattern.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
class myclass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__age=None
    @property
    def age(self):
        if self.__age is None:
            self.__age=21  #This can be a long computation
        return self.__age
```

Alex mentioned you can use `__getattr__`, this is how it works

```
class myclass(object):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr=="age":
            self.age=21   #This can be a long computation
        return super(myclass, self).__getattribute__(attr)
```

`__getattr__()` is invoked when the attribute doesn't exist on the object, ie. the first time you try to access `age`. Every time after, `age` exists so `__getattr__` doesn't get called

Comment: the call to `return getattr(self, attr)` would cause an infinite loop if attr doesn't exist. Use `return super(MyClass, self).__getattr__(attr)` instead.

Comment: No doubt __getattr__ should return self.age if attr=='age', rather than calling super's __getattr__.

Comment: @~unutbu, The `super.__getattr__` does return `self.age` once it has been created

Comment: print(myclass().age) returns AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'. Am I missing something?

Comment: @~unutbu, I had `MyClass` instead of `myclass` also. oops. It's fixed now

Answer (score 6):

`property`, as you've seen, will not let you override it.  You need to use a slightly different approach, such as:

```
class myclass(object):

    @property
    def age(self):
      if not hasattr(self, '_age'):
        self._age = self._big_long_computation()
      return self._age
```

There are other approaches, such as `__getattr__` or a custom descriptor class, but this one is simpler!-)

Comment: @nosklo, oops, been doing too much C lately -- fixed, tx

Answer (score 5):

[Here](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/0596007973/pythoncook2-CHP-20-SECT-4) is decorator from [Python Cookbook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596007973/) for this problem:

```
class CachedAttribute(object):
    ''' Computes attribute value and caches it in the instance. '''
    def __init__(self, method, name=None):
        # record the unbound-method and the name
        self.method = method
        self.name = name or method.__name__
    def __get__(self, inst, cls):
        if inst is None:
            # instance attribute accessed on class, return self
            return self
        # compute, cache and return the instance's attribute value
        result = self.method(inst)
        setattr(inst, self.name, result)
        return result
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use properties, though lazy evaluation is also often accomplished using descriptors, see e.g:

http://blog.pythonisito.com/2008/08/lazy-descriptors.html

Answer (score 1):

This question is already 11 years old, and python 3.8 and above now come with [cached_property](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property), which perfectly serves this purpose. The property will be computed only once, then kept in memory for subsequent use.

Here is how to use it in this case:

```
class myclass(object):
    @cached_property
    def age(self):
        return 21  #This can be a long computation
```