# Python 3 - Check class attribute without calling __getattr__

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, attributes, hasattr

TL;DR: Are there alternatives to `hasattr` which don't trigger property getters?

I'm writing a Python interface to some existing code where I am getting and setting values for various shape and section classes. Due to a large number of possible combinations, I currently create new classes dynamically, subclassing a `SectionHandler` class and shape class, such as `Circle`. Each has specific methods that I want to preserve.

As this API will be used in scripts and interactively, I want to make sure that any attributes modified after class instantiation already exists (so that new attributes can't be created from typos and the user is warned when a non-existent attribute is specified). Since this check needs to 'skip' all the new attributes being added during sub-classing, I preload the attributes into the new class using the attributes dictionary in the `type` function (represented below by the `name` and `index` attributes).

I'm using `hasattr` to check if the attribute exists in the created class by overriding `__setattr__`, as suggested in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137558/python-can-a-class-forbid-clients-setting-new-attributes). This works when the attribute does not exist but the issue is when the attribute does exist - since `hasattr` seems to work by calling the property getter, I get extraneous logging calls from the getter, which pollutes the log over many attribute modifications (especially for longer messages).

Is there another way to check for a class attribute in dynamically generated classes? I tried looking in `self.__dict__` instead of using `hasattr` but that dictionary is empty at class creation time. What alternatives are there?

I've tried to give a minimal working example that reflects the structure I'm working with below:

```
import logging

class CurveBase:
    """Base class for all curves/shapes."""
    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        """Restrict to setting of existing attributes only."""
        if hasattr(self, attr):
            return super().__setattr__(attr, value)
        else:
            raise AttributeError(f'{attr} does not exist in {self.__class__.__name__}')


class Circle(CurveBase):
    """Circle-type shape base class."""
    @property
    def diameter(self):
        logging.info(f'Getting {self.name} section {self.index} diameter')
        # diameter = external_getter("Circle_Diameter")
        # return diameter

    @diameter.setter
    def diameter(self, diameter):
        logging.info(f'Setting {self.name} section {self.index} diameter to: {diameter}')
        # external_setter("Circle_Diameter", diameter)


class SectionHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        # Minimal example init
        self.name = 'section_1'
        self.index = 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # This is set up by the API code
    logging.basicConfig(level='INFO', format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    shape = 'circle'
    attribute_dict = {'name': None, 'index': None}  # Generated based on classes used.
    NewSectionClass = type(f'{shape.capitalize()}Section',
                           (SectionHandler, Circle),
                           attribute_dict)
    section = NewSectionClass()


    # This is an example of API usage
    print(section.diameter)
    # Returns:
    # 2018-12-04 18:53:07,805 - INFO - Getting section_1 section 1 diameter
    # None  # <-- this would be a value from external_getter

    section.diameter = 5
    # Returns:
    # 2018-12-04 18:53:07,805 - INFO - Getting section_1 section 1 diameter  # <-- extra getter call from hasattr()!!!
    # 2018-12-04 18:53:07,805 - INFO - Setting section_1 section 1 diameter to: 5

    section.non_existent
    # Correctly returns:
    # Traceback (most recent call last):
    #   File "scratch_1.py", line 50, in <module>
    #     section.non_existent
    # AttributeError: 'CircleSection' object has no attribute 'non_existent'
```

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

You must try calling `<Object>.__getattribute__()` and catch error

### Your Case

Something like this could work

```py
class CurveBase:
    """Base class for all curves/shapes."""
    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        """Restrict to setting of existing attributes only."""
        try:
            super().__getattribute__(attr)
            return super().__setattr__(attr, value)
        except:
            raise AttributeError(f'{attr} does not exist in {self.__class__.__name__}')
```

### Alternatives

- `getattr_static()` from `inspect` module as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58248587)
- You can also wrap `__getattribute__` try catch into a bool function like in the answer from point 1.

### References

- Python [documentation for `__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__)
- Some hints from the latter section of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1598204)