# Cheking if an object has an attribute, without relying on '__getattr__'

Tags: python

Is there a way to check if an object has an attribute, that doesn't rely on `__getattr__` or object implementation specifics?

Consider the code below. I want `Proxy` to delegate to `Wrapped` what it can't handle. The code works, but I'd like to avoid the test `attr in self.__dict__` (I'd prefer a stable interface to do this, without using implementation quirks). The function `hasattr` doesn't help here, because it gets routed to the wrapped object via `__getattr__`.

```
class Wrapped:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0
        self.b = 1

class Proxy:
    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        object.__setattr__(self, 'wrapped', wrapped)
        object.__setattr__(self, 'a', 2)
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.wrapped, attr)
    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        if attr in self.__dict__:  # <-- Don't like this, hasattr doesn't work
            object.__setattr__(self, attr, value)
        elif hasattr(self.wrapped, attr):
            setattr(self.wrapped, attr, value)
        else: object.__setattr__(self, attr, value)
```

Testdrive:

```
>>> w = Wrapped()
>>> p = Proxy(w)
>>> p.a
2
>>> p.b
1
>>> p.a = 3
>>> p.a
3
>>> w.a
0
>>> p.b = 4
>>> p.b
4
>>> w.b
4
>>> p.c = 5
>>> p.c
5
>>> w.c
AttributeError: 'Wrapped' object has no attribute 'c'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in [`hasattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr) function

> is implemented by calling `getattr(object, name)` and seeing whether it raises an `AttributeError` or not.

The [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module has the [`getattr_static()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getattr_static) method, which can be used to

> Retrieve attributes without triggering dynamic lookup via the descriptor protocol, `__getattr__()` or `__getattribute__()`".

Using this method, you could define a `hasattr_static()` method similarly to `hasattr()`, but calling `inspect.getattr_static(object, name)` instead of `getattr(object, name)`:

```
import inspect


def hasattr_static(object, name):
    try:
        inspect.getattr_static(object, name)
        return True
    except AttributeError:
        return False
```

And then use this in the `__setattr__()` method of your `Proxy` class as a check:

```
def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
    if hasattr_static(self, attr):
        object.__setattr__(self, attr, value)
    elif hasattr(self.wrapped, attr):
        setattr(self.wrapped, attr, value)
    else:
        object.__setattr__(self, attr, value)
```

Alternatively, you coud use the [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#dir) function instead of `__dict__` to retrieve a list of attributes of your object, or use [`inspect.getmembers()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers).